# PHPstorm, grunt task runs only when I change window

Tags: gruntjs, phpstorm

I'm trying to set up grunt to make it work directly from PHPStorm. I work on a Mac. Normally I edit code on PHPStorm and in another terminal window I have, for example, a `grunt watch` task running to process `scss` files.
Running the task from PHPStorm happens that it stays on "waiting", no matter how many changes I make in a file being watched, but the moment I switch window, from PHPStorm to the browser or anything else, the task starts running. Is this a normal behavior or is there an option to control it? Or something is actually wrong?

Comment: Could you add your grunt task, and files/folder structure that you watch, please?

Comment: Try to use built in grunt watchers. https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/using-grunt-task-runner.html they will fire on file change

Comment: when you switch a window, PHPStorm performs Save All (if 'Save files on frame deactivation' is enabled), thus your grunt watcher is triggered. Did you try saving files explicitly in PHPStorm (using File/Save All)?

Comment: You also can compile a scss files in PHPStorm only with a watchers functionality...

Comment: @lena, thanks, that's the reason why it's happening and with Save All it works. I guess the proper way to do it would be to use the PHPStorm watchers. If you post an answer I'll accept it as the correct one